# android: xml attribute android:onClick, why the method needs View parameter

Tags: android, xml, onclick

When I create an android:onClick attribute in the activity's xml, the method defined by onClick needs to have the View parameter, why View?

i.e.
onClick method in my activity----------> public void sayHello(View v){...}

consider the next code, I'm not using the view variable, but I still need to pass it in method, how come?:

```
public void onClick(View view){
        TextView t= new TextView(this);
        t=(TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textView2);
        t.setText("new text");
    }
```

Comment: If you have five buttons calling the same `onClick` method, the argument you're asking about is the only thing that will tell you which button was clicked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

So you know which `View` is calling the method.
It's like implementing the `OnClickListener` for you activity, the method created is `onClick(View v)` (or `arg0` depending on your Eclipse), defining it from xml is just specifying a sort of listener for the View, and the method from the listener as that argument.

Once you're in the method, you can do a switch for the id of the button, to perform different actions:

```
public void myOnClickMethod(View v){
    switch(v.getId()){
       case R.id.button1:
          //Do something for button 1
       break;
       case R.id.button2:
          //Do something for button 2
       break;
    }
}
```

**In short.** Android just implements the `OnClickListener` for you when you define the `android:onClick="myOnClickMethod"` attribute.

Answer (score 1):

Before answering the question I would like to mention what a view is...

Android app contains activities which are like screens which further contains GUI elements(such as buttons). In simple words, those GUI elements are called views.

Answer for your question...

Just imagine a situation in which your activity has more than one button (Let's consider it to be 5) and on getting clicked those buttons make a call to the same function (namely onClick()).So, how would the program know which button was clicked. The answer is simple just pass a view parameter to the onClick() function which will allow access to the information regarding the button that was clicked.